# Spring boot AOP Aspect not being invoked

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spring-aop, aspect

I'm trying to intercept rest service calls with an aspect in the following manner

```
 package mypackage.services.Service;

 @Component
 public class Service {

      @Override
      public Response helloService() {
        return handleResult("Hello test " + new Date());
      }
 }
```

---

```
@Component
@Aspect
public class AuditLog {

     @Before("execution(* mypackage.services.Service.*(..))")
     public void beforeServcie(JoinPoint jp){
       log.info("Before ",jp.getSignature().getName());
     }
}
```

I'm using the following maven dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

This maven plugin

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </plugin>
```

And my configuration xml contains

```
   <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="mypackage"/>
    <aop:aspectj-autoproxy proxy-target-class="true" />
```

also in the Application class I've added the following annotation

```
  @Configuration
  @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
  public class Configuration{
   ...
  }
```

On startup, by logging beans in the ApplicationContext, I can see that the aspect class "AuditLog" is being created.

I've set 2 breakpoints, but the debugger does not stop at the "beforeServcie" method but it does stop at the "helloService".

What am I missing?

Comment: tried, but it didn't work

Comment: you dont need all these aspectj dependencies

Comment: why do you have a separate xml config?

Comment: proxyTargetClass=true is not needed

Comment: Which dependencies are superfluous? I've removed targetClass=True, but it still does not pass from the Aspect method

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
execution(* mypackage.services.Service.*.*(..))
```

instead of

```
execution(* mypackage.services.Service.*(..))
```

Comment: if you are using spring boot no need to add dependencies, config.xml and @EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true) in config class

Comment: If I remove the dependencies (i.e. spring-aop, aspectjrt), I get compile errors on the '@Aspect', '@AfterReturning' and '@Before' annotations

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using spring-boot then instead of automatically adding dependency jars you can do

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. If you're using XML config `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy ... />` then no need to have `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy`. It probably doesn't matter since AFAIK XML config wins over annotation config but better to avoid duplication
3. I am not quite sure why do you need `aspectj-maven-plugin` since Spring implements AOP by proxy and AFAIK this plugin is only needed for compile-time, post compile-time or load time weaving which are different concepts, see [Spring AOP vs AspectJ](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-aop-vs-aspectj)

Now all the above mentioned points may not resolve your issue but the following might

```
execution(* mypackage.services.Service.Service.*(..))
```

And, don't set `proxyTargetClass=true`, let it be default false.

**Explanation**

The format is `execution(<return type> <package name>.<class name>.<method name>(..)`

The package name here is mypackage.services.Service and the class name is Service.

Comment: Thanks for the reply after 3 years. I removed the proxyTargetClass=true from the configuration and used  @Before("execution(* mypackage.services.Service.*(..))") but got no luck :(

Comment: @AhaduTsegayeAbebe you said you tried `mypackage.services.Service.*` but what was suggested is `mypackage.services.Service.Service.*`

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention that I corrected the package to  'mypackage.services;'